# What is the preferred way of Image file handling for Spring Framework?

Tags: java, spring, image, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have a project to create web services that would accept and manipulate images as a response using Spring.

I know the concept of RESTful APIs for Spring specifically for XML and JSON responses, the bindings with the java objects using the Jackson library, but I was looking for the same kind of thing but for other content-types like images.

I have the below functionality to upload and fetch the image but I am not sure on what @RequestBody object is needed to bind Image POJOs like BufferedImage so that I could manipulate it in the future.

```
// Upload the image from a browser through AJAX with URI "../upload"
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"image/png", "image/jpeg"})
protected void upload(@RequestBody ???){
    // upload the image in a webserver as an Image POJO to make some image manipulation in the future. 
}

// Fetches the image from a webserver through GET request with URI "../fetch/{image}"
@RequestMapping(value="/fetch/{image}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
protected @ResponseBody String fetch(@PathVariable("image") String imageName){
    // fetch image from a webserver as a String with the path of the image location to be display by img html tag.
}
```

With this, I was looking for a more preferred way of doing the image file handling for Spring with a more concise explanation.

I have also read about **BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter** but not quite sure if it is useful to my application.

Thank you!

Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need for uploading is usual upload file.

```
@PostMapping("/upload") // //new annotation since 4.3
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                               RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
```

The code from [the example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/)

So you just send the file by POST with "multipart/form-data"

For downloading you should just write the image file bytes

```
@GetMapping(value = "/image")
public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = getClass()
      .getResourceAsStream("/com/baeldung/produceimage/image.jpg");
    return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
}
```

The code from [the example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file)

Comment: Can I use @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST) instead of @PostMapping right?

Comment: I think yes but you can try. I know nothing about your configs, spring version etc. It's much easier/faster to try.